# SQL create two tables

Tags: sql

I have to create two tables in SQL one with employees and one with their projects. The problem is: one employee can work to one or more projects and on a project can work one or more employees and I don't know how to create these 2 tables and how to put the foreign keys. I guess the primary keys are the IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship. You need three tables: Employee, Project, and EmployeeProject. EmployeeProject would have two columns EmployeeId and ProjectId. Its sole purpose would be to represent the relationship between Employee and Project.

Comment: Ok, I understand, and this 3th table will have 2 foreign keys?

Comment: Correct. The two id columns in EmployeeProject would be foreign keys to the primary keys of the respective tables.

Comment: No problem. Once you get this data model set up all you have to do to fetch the data is to inner join across EmployeeProject. So for example if you wanted the list of projects that an employee is involved with you would do something like:

SELECT p.*
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ep ON e.EmployeeId = ep.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN Project p ON p.ProjectId = ep.ProjectId
WHERE e.Name = 'Cipryst'

Comment: Thanks again, I have to save this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create third table which is link employee to projects
like below:
Project Table:

```
ID  ProjName  Date ...
```

Employee Table:

```
ID EmpName ....
```

Link Table:

```
ID EmpID  ProjID
```

Comment: Thank you, but in the Projecttbl and Employeetbl do I have to put another column with foreign key for the Linktbl?

Comment: @Cipryst No you don't have to do so.